# Cannot find class in java

Tags: java

Here is my directory

```
--MainFolder
----src
-------zad1
---------server
------------AddressInfoServer.class
```

Now, I am in folder server (MainFolder/src/zad1/server), and I am trying to run `AddressInfoServer.class` like this:

```
java AddressInfoServer
```

but I receive error of:

> Could not find or load main class `AddressInfoServer.class`

Here is my compiled `AddressInfoServer.class`:

```
package zad1;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import zad1.AddressInfo;

public class AddressInfoServer {
    public AddressInfoServer() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] var0) {
        try {
            System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
            System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://localhost:3333");
            AddressInfo var1 = new AddressInfo();
            InitialContext var2 = new InitialContext();
            var2.rebind("AddressInfoService", var1);
        } catch (Exception var3) {
            var3.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: First of all, how did your code compile with this wrong package declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package seems not correct.

A class present in a subdirectory `zad1/server` should have package

```
package zad1.server;
```

To launch it

```
java zad1.server.AddressInfoServer
```

Comment: Is this the way to launch it from the server folder (the same folder where AddressInfoServer class is)?

Answer (score 1):

Your package is wrong.  Since your class lives inside of zad1/server, your package needs to reflect this.

```
package zad1.server;
```

To invoke it, you'd use class' fully qualified name:

```
java zad1.server.AddressInfoServer
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:-

1) package declaration: `package zad1.server;`

2) run the class while you are at `MainFolder/src` and invoke `java zad1.server.AddressInfoServer`

Please tell me whether it works or not.